# Recycle Bin script in batch

Tags: file, input, batch-file

I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2.

My script verifies that the files I enter exist and then verifies that the files I want to move don't already exist in `recycleBin.dir`.  There's also a choice to overwrite the file or not; if you choose "yes," the script moves them.

My problem is I need to be able to input multiple files, not just one.

What I've done:

```
@echo off
set param = "%*"
set corb_path=c:\corbeille.dir
set rep_courant = %cd%
:debut
if "%*" == "" goto error
goto path
goto end
:path
cd %corb_path%|| del %corb_path%
if not exist %corb_path%/nul mkdir %corb_path%
cd c:\
if exist %rep_courant%%* goto something 
  ) else ( 
goto end )
:something
if exist %corb_path%\"%*" goto choice
 ) else ( 
 goto 1 )
:choice 
choice /t 10 /d n /c on /cs /m "fichier "(%*)" file exist in corbeille.dir"
if errorlevel 2 goto 2
if errorlevel 1 goto 1 
:1
move %* %corb_path%
shift
goto debut 
:2
echo the file has beed deleted
goto end
:error
echo "You need to input something"
:end
```

Answer (score 1):

You want your script to process each file passed in as command line parameters?

From what I see of the bat, you will need to change a few lines.  The major issue is with using the `%*`.  This will pull in all the parameters at once and not one at a time.  You will want to use `%1`.

Change Line 6:

```
if "%1" == "" goto error
```

Change Line 13:

```
if exist %rep_courant%%1 goto something
```

Change Line 17:

```
if exist %corb_path%\"%1" goto choice
```

Change Line 21:

```
choice /t 10 /d n /c on /cs /m "fichier "(%1)" file exist in corbeille.dir"
```

Change Line 25:

```
move %1 %corb_path%
```

The `%1` will always have the next item due to the `shift` command.

There are also some other changes in reagards to strings, quotations, and spaces that I might address later in an updated answer, but the changes above should do what you want.

BTW: Line 2 and 8 are doing nothing useful in the script.  They can be removed.